# Get value of input datetime-local with jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetime, input

I have an input type text:

```
<input type="text"
        name="rif_p_<?=$rif['code']?>"
        id="rif_p_<?=$rif['code']?>" />
```

And a datetime-local

```
<input type="datetime-local"
       name="rif_from_<?=$rif['code']?>"
       id="rif_from_<?=$rif['code']?>" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('[id^=rif_p_]').on('keyup change', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    alert(value);  /* alerts correctly the value */
});


$('[id^=rif_from_]').on('keyup click change', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    alert(value);  /* alerts '' */
});
```

Now the first alert for text input correctly alerts the value that the user inputs on the field; with datetime-local value is always empty.

Why?

Thank you

Note: obviously this alert is only for test purposes

**EDIT:**

Ok I found the solution, if the complete date/time is not select val is empty.

Now that's my complete jQuery function, which updates the values before I can insert completely a date/time. With text this works, so how can I correct it also to work with datetime?

```
$('[id^=rif_from_]').on('keyup click change', function(){

    var rif_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');

    var id = rif_id[2];
    var value = $(this).val();

    /* This also updates the corrent editing element! So with datetime = '' */
    $('[id$=_from_'+id+']').val(value);
});
```

Comment: Have you selected a time?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/6sc44/